# Separate JavaScript file from PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this JavaScript code embedded in a `.php` file. I want to place the JavaScript in a separate file and link to the .php file using the link tag.

I tried but did not work:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function date_time(id)
{
    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('January', 'February',
    'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 
    'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    h = date.getHours();
    if(h<10)
    {
            h = "0"+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if(m<10)
    {
            m = "0"+m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if(s<10)
    {
            s = "0"+s;
    }
    result = ''+days[day]+' '+months[month]+' '+d+' '+year+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
    return true;
    }
    </script>

    <footer>

        &lt; &trade;&gt;&nbsp;
        <span id="date_time"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" >window.onload = date_time('date_time'); 
         </script>
    </footer>
```

The time calculated by the Javascript did not show at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the javascript file be called using <script src=""> inside your php file. That should work, otherwise, please explain fully your issue

Comment: you need to link it with <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jsfile.js">

Comment: You really need some basic HTML before even starting PHP projects.
Checkout w3schools.

Comment: @Houssni Check out http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @DainisAbols Interesting, thanks for tipping!

Comment: The code I posted is in a single file footer.php and I want to just make the javascript code separate from the php file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
```

and not use the `<link>` tag which is for CSS files [edit] and favicon files[/edit]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. W3Schools.com states that it is `is most used to link to style sheets.`. What kind of file would you link with it?

Comment: Favicons *(Icon that's viewed beside your page title)* as example ;)

Comment: Right! Completely forgot about favicon! Thanks

Comment: links are also used to show relationships (ala the `rel` attribute)

Comment: The code I posted is in a single file footer.php and I want to just make the javascript code separate from the php file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your JS file with a script tag, not a link tag inside your php

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have html in your .js file, but you can have javascript in .html files. However, I am not 100% sure if this is what you are asking for, but I guess you should try to include this file into your php-file, instead of the other way around.

```
<?php include 'path/to/html_and_javascript_file.html'; ?>
```

Comment: No need to do that when you can just call the .js file with a script tag in the php file

Comment: I wasn't sure about if he wanted to have the html-code in the file as well. Sure there stands javascript, but there are still html-code in his post, but no php, which was what he wanted to separate it from. That's why I wrote I wasn't 100% sure about what he was asking for :)

Comment: The code I posted is in a single file footer.php and I want to just make the javascript code separate from the php file.